# PHP using session in a MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I can echo the session name so i know its working but it doesn't work in a MySQL query. I even tried turning it into a variable and its still not working:

File list:
index.php
response.php

```
$repname = $_SESSION['name'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `employee` WHERE rep='".$repname."' ";
```

also

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `employee` WHERE rep=".$_SESSION['name']." ";
```

any ideas on what's wrong?

UPDATE**

Here's the right query

```
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `employee` WHERE rep='".$_SESSION['name']."' ";
```

I know its the right query because now i'm getting records to display but its only records where rep is blank. This means i'm not getting the session name for some reason.

I tried adding:

```
     session_start();
 if(isset($_GET['name'])){
 $_SESSION['name']=$_GET['name'];
  }
```

But im still only getting records where rep is blank

Comment: No errors? And I think you mean `$repname = $_SESSION['name']` not `$_SESSION['name'] = $repname`

Comment: i don't see any errors :(

Comment: if its a string, then you should properly quote it, you do know that it unsafe, you should prepare the statement instead

Comment: its having value or not in $repname or $_SESSION['name'] ?

Comment: ... don't see any errors... you mean, apart from the apparent SQL Injection vulnerability.  ie. what happens when the value in `$_SESSION['name']` happens to contain a quote e.g.."`O'Reilly`".  Of course, we only see code that sets a variable to a string. We don't see any code that attempts to execute that SQL statement.

Comment: "doesn't work" is an inadequate description of the observed behavior. For debugging, enable PHP error reporting. And echo or var_dump the SQL statement before it's submitted to the database. And check the return from the database for an error condition (with most interface libraries, the return will be FALSE rather than a resultset (or statement handle, if we are using prepared statements.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to add session_start() to the top of your session to initiate your session start

```
    <?php
    session_start(); ?>
```

Also be sure to add this to retrieve your name field:

```
<?php 
     session_start();
     if(isset($_GET['name']){
     $_SESSION['name']=$_GET['name'];

 ?>
```